# What spacing to use between microstrip trace and ground plane on same layer?

Tags: pcb-design, ground, hardware, microstrip, multi-layer

I am designing a 4 layer board (1 - signal, 2 - GND, 3 - power, 4 - signal) and I have some microstrip lines on top and bottom layers.

**Should I fill the top and bottom layer with ground?** What do you recommend? I intend to do so, but I don't know what **clearance to keep between the microstrips and the ground planes on the same layer**.

Comment: If you are going to fill the top and bottom with a ground pour, then simply use coplanar waveguide. https://chemandy.com/calculators/coplanar-waveguide-with-ground-calculator.htm

Comment: @PeterSmith Thanks for the suggestion, but I would like to use microstrips. So, in this case I guess your suggestion is to avoid filling the top and bottom layers with ground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule of thumb for clearance either side of microstrip lines is three substrate thicknesses. The reduction of microstrip impedance due to the adjacent ground will be minimal for most purposes other than precision metrology.

There will be some slight coupling of the signal onto the adjacent grounds, so they should be adequately grounded by vias to the microstrip ground, at least every λ/10, to prevent coupling into structures that might become inadvertently resonant at some frequencies.

If you are going to use gaps of less than three substrate thicknesses, then consider designing the line as CPWG, coplanar with ground, for which there are many design resources available.

Comment: I've heard the 3W rule described as 3x the trace width, rather than 3x substrate thickness. I believe it applies to the substrate thickness as you describe, but can you confirm?

Comment: @JYelton Yes, I meant substrate thicknesses, though for the last 20 years I've only been working in one substrate Er (4ish). It feels like with alumina (10) or PTFE (2), the separation might scale more with trace width than substrate thickness. Perhaps you could use one of the online coupled-line calculators. Move the lines apart and see when the proximity effects drop to say 1% of 'very close', and let me know what you find.